# SAML Assertion Error

Tags: oauth, cloud, identity, saml

A Cloud service I am trying to use is asking for this:

```
Enter Attribute containing Login Name . This attribute is used for authentication of
end-user. This is the attribute name that maps to the LDAP email address. From the XML 
meta-data, find: <NameID>user@example.com<NameID>. NameID is what is to be copied into 
this field. In some cases, this attribute may also be found at <Attribute 
Name"https://schema/xml.soap.org/.....identity/claims/name"> 
<AttributeValue>user@example.com<AttributeValue>.  In these cases, name is the attribute 
value.
```

I am using SimpleSAMLPHP as my IDP. What exactly do I need to enter here?

Comment: Post an example of the SAML assertion you're passing to the cloud service. The Cloud service is looking for a login name / user id and isn't finding it in the SAML assertion you're submitting to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup your userid in the NameID field you may look into the IdP config:

- http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.10/simplesamlphp-reference-idp-hosted#section_2

In particular the `attributes.NameFormat` which tells which kind of Name Identifier to use.

Use this together with the `userid.attribute` to set a specific attribute value in the NameID field.

Otherwise, as mentioned, if the userid is in one of the attributes, you need to know the name of the attribute, which may be inherited from the authentication source, such as LDAP.